# Possible to loop through excel files with differently named sheets, and import into a list?

Tags: python, r

I do not have a reproducible example for this but asking it based on interest.

With a loop function in R, we are able to obtain all .csv from a directory with the below code:

```
file.list <- list.files(pattern='*.csv') #obtained name of all the files in directory
df.list <- lapply(file.list, read.csv) #list
```

Would it be possible for us to loop through a directory with .xlsx files instead with different number of sheets?

For instance: A.xlsx contains 3 sheets, Jan01, Sheet2 and Sheet3; B.xlsx contains 3 sheets, Jan02, Sheet2 and Sheet3 ... and so on. The first sheet name changes.

Is it possible to loop through a directory and just obtain the dataframes for the first sheet in all excel files?

Python or R codes are welcome!

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

another (fast) R-solution using the `readxl`-package

```
l <- lapply( file.list, readxl::read_excel, sheet = 1 )
```

Answer (score 4):

**In R**

Here is an `R` solution using the package `openxlsx`

```
# get all xlsx files in given directory
filesList <- list.files("d:/Test/", pattern = '.*\\.xlsx', full.names = TRUE)

# pre-allocate list of first sheet names
firstSheetList <- rep(list(NA),length(filesList))

# loop through files and get the data of first sheets
for (k in seq_along(filesList)) 
  firstSheetList[[k]] <- openxlsx::read.xlsx(filesList[k], sheet = 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure, its possible using `pandas` and `python`.

```
import pandas as pd

excel_file = pd.ExcelFile('A.xlsx')
dataframes = {sheet: excel_file.parse(sheet) for sheet in excel_file.sheet_names}
```

`dataframes` becomes a dictionary, with the keys being the names of the sheets, and the values becoming the dataframe containing the sheet data.  You can iterate through them like so:

```
for k,v in dataframes.items():
    print('Sheetname: %s' % k)
    print(v.head())
```

Answer (score 2):

By using [Openpyxl](http://www.pythonexcel.com/openpyxl.php)

`get_sheet_names()`.

This function returns the names of the sheets in a workbook and you can count the names to tell about total number of sheets in current workbook. The code will be:

```
>>> wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('testfile.xlsx')
>>> wb.get_sheet_names()
['S1, 'S2', 'S3']
```

we can access any sheet at one time. Lets suppose we want to access Sheet3. Following code should be written

```
>>> import openpyxl
>>> wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('testfile.xlsx')
>>> wb.get_sheet_names()
['Sheet1', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet3']
>>> sheet=wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet3')
```

The function `get_sheet_by_name('Sheet3')` is used to access a particular sheet. This function takes the name of sheet as argument and returns a sheet object. We store that in a variable and can use it like...

```
>>> sheet
<Worksheet "Sheet3">
>>> type(sheet)
<class 'openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet'>
>>> sheet.title
'Sheet3'
>>>
```

and eventually:

```
worksheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet3')    
for row_cells in worksheet.iter_rows():
    for cell in row_cells:
       print('%s: cell.value=%s' % (cell, cell.value) )
```

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, lets say we had two workbooks with the first sheet in this format:

[image]

You can iterate over each `.xlsx` file in the directory with [`glob.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob), and append the dataframe of the first sheet with [`pandas.ExcelFile.parse()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.ExcelFile.parse.html) to a list:

```
from glob import glob
import pandas as pd

sheets = []

# Go through each xlsx file
for xlsx_file in glob("*.xlsx"):

    # Convert sheet to dataframe
    xlsx = pd.ExcelFile(xlsx_file)

    # Get first sheet and append it
    sheet_1 = xlsx.parse(0)
    sheets.append(sheet_1)

print(sheets)
```

Which prints two dataframes contained in a list:

```
[   x  y
0  1  2
1  1  2,    x  y
0  1  2
1  1  2]
```

You can also write the above as a *list comprehension*:

```
[pd.ExcelFile(xlsx_file).parse(0) for xlsx_file in glob("*.xlsx")]
```

You could also store the dataframes into a dictionary with filenames as the key:

```
{xlsx_file: pd.ExcelFile(xlsx_file).parse(0) for xlsx_file in glob("*.xlsx")}
```